# Optimize this chain of Views

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a set of 6 Viewsthat i use to gather the data i need for an excel report.

View 1

```
SELECT        *, MONTH(DataEmissione) AS Mese_Emissione, YEAR(DataEmissione) AS Anno_Emissione, CASE WHEN StatoEmissione = 'R' THEN - ImpVetComp WHEN StatoBiglietto = 'VR' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 WHEN StatoEmissione = 'NC' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 WHEN StatoEmissione = 'AN' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 ELSE                           ImpVetComp END AS Fare, DATENAME(month, DataEmissione) AS Issue_Month_Name, DATEPART(quarter, DataEmissione) AS Quarter, YEAR(DATEADD(month, - 3, DataEmissione)) AS AnnoFiscale, CASE WHEN MONTH(DataEmissione) < 4 THEN MONTH(DataEmissione) + 9 ELSE MONTH(DataEmissione) - 3 END AS Fiscal_Month, REPLACE(REPLACE(Destinazione, ' ', ''), '-', '') AS Destinazione_Normalizzata
FROM            Gabbiano.dbo.PRAB0000
WHERE        (DataEmissione >= DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE()))
UNION ALL
SELECT        *, MONTH(DataEmissione) AS Mese_Emissione, YEAR(DataEmissione) AS Anno_Emissione, CASE WHEN StatoEmissione = 'R' THEN - ImpVetComp WHEN StatoBiglietto = 'VR' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 WHEN StatoEmissione = 'NC' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 WHEN StatoEmissione = 'AN' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 ELSE                           ImpVetComp END AS Fare, DATENAME(month, DataEmissione) AS Issue_Month_Name, DATEPART(quarter, DataEmissione) AS Quarter, YEAR(DATEADD(month, - 3, DataEmissione)) AS AnnoFiscale, CASE WHEN MONTH(DataEmissione) < 4 THEN MONTH(DataEmissione) + 9 ELSE MONTH(DataEmissione) - 3 END AS Fiscal_Month, REPLACE(REPLACE(Destinazione, ' ', ''), '-', '') AS Destinazione_Normalizzata
FROM            Istantravel.dbo.PRAB0000
WHERE        (DataEmissione >= DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE()))
UNION ALL
SELECT        *, MONTH(DataEmissione) AS Mese_Emissione, YEAR(DataEmissione) AS Anno_Emissione, CASE WHEN StatoEmissione = 'R' THEN - ImpVetComp WHEN StatoBiglietto = 'VR' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 WHEN StatoEmissione = 'NC' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 WHEN StatoEmissione = 'AN' THEN ImpVetComp * 0 ELSE                           ImpVetComp END AS Fare, DATENAME(month, DataEmissione) AS Issue_Month_Name, DATEPART(quarter, DataEmissione) AS Quarter, YEAR(DATEADD(month, - 3, DataEmissione)) AS AnnoFiscale, CASE WHEN MONTH(DataEmissione) < 4 THEN MONTH(DataEmissione) + 9 ELSE MONTH(DataEmissione) - 3 END AS Fiscal_Month, REPLACE(REPLACE(Destinazione, ' ', ''), '-', '') AS Destinazione_Normalizzata
FROM            Globmaster.dbo.PRAB0000
WHERE        (DataEmissione >= DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE()))
```

Views 2

```
SELECT        biglietti.Agenzia, biglietti.CodiceCompagnia, biglietti.StatoBiglietto, biglietti.StatoEmissione, biglietti.CodicePersonale, biglietti.TipoTratta, biglietti.ClasseVettore, biglietti.MastroCliente, biglietti.SottocCliente, 
                         biglietti.DataEmissione, biglietti.DataVariazione, biglietti.DataPartenza, biglietti.ImponibileVettore, biglietti.TasseAerop, biglietti.ImpCorrispettivi, biglietti.CorrispettiviAdd, biglietti.ScontoCommissioni, 
                         biglietti.NumeroPax, biglietti.Destinazione, biglietti.ImpVetComp, biglietti.ImportoComm, biglietti.ImportoCommPass, biglietti.NumeroBiglietto, biglietti.NomePasseggero, biglietti.TasseYQ, biglietti.TasseYR, 
                         biglietti.CodicePnr, biglietti.Mese_Emissione, biglietti.Anno_Emissione, biglietti.Fare, biglietti.Nome_Mese_Emissione, biglietti.Quarter, biglietti.Prop, biglietti.AnnoFiscale, 
                         compagnie.Descrizione AS NomeCompagnia, compagnie.Categoria, compagnie.Alleanza, 
                         CASE WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'VOID' THEN 'VOID' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'CNJ' THEN 'CAMBI' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'conj' THEN 'CONGIUNZIONI'
                          WHEN datalength(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata) 
                         = 0 THEN 'NON INDICATA' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata LIKE 'OR.ISSUE%' THEN 'RIEMISSIONI' ELSE SUBSTRING(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata, 1, 3) END AS Partenza, 
                         CASE WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'VOID' THEN 'VOID' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'CNJ' THEN 'CAMBI' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'conj' THEN 'CONGIUNZIONI'
                          WHEN datalength(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata) 
                         = 0 THEN 'NON INDICATA' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata LIKE 'OR.ISSUE%' THEN 'RIEMISSIONI' ELSE SUBSTRING(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata, LEN(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata) 
                         / 2 + 1 - 3, 3) END AS Arrivo, 
                         CASE WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'VOID' THEN 'VOID' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'CNJ' THEN 'CAMBI' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'conj' THEN 'CONGIUNZIONI'
                          WHEN datalength(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata) 
                         = 0 THEN 'NON INDICATA' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata LIKE 'OR.ISSUE%' THEN 'RIEMISSIONI' ELSE SUBSTRING(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata, LEN(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata) 
                         / 2 + 1, 3) END AS DestinazioneFinale, 
                         CASE WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'VOID' THEN 'VOID' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'CNJ' THEN 'CAMBI' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata = 'conj' THEN 'CONGIUNZIONI'
                          WHEN datalength(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata) 
                         = 0 THEN 'NON INDICATA' WHEN biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata LIKE 'OR.ISSUE%' THEN 'RIEMISSIONI' ELSE RIGHT(biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata, 3) END AS Ritorno, biglietti.Mese_Fiscale, 
                         biglietti.Destinazione_Normalizzata, biglietti.CodiceBiglietto
FROM            dbo.Biglietti AS biglietti INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Compagnie AS compagnie ON biglietti.CodiceCompagnia = compagnie.Codice
WHERE        (biglietti.DataEmissione >= DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE()))
```

And the other Views are similar.
Each is needed to performs calculations columns added with each Views.
However i reckon it's a bit inefficient.
How you would solve this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but all that text in a language I don't understand makes it very hard to read. Simplify/minimize, and use English names.

Comment: The focus is not on the SQL language. I'd like to know what i can use to perform all those calculations instead of a chain of vistas like i currently have (Vista 1 reads from Table - Vista 2 reads from Vista 1 - Vista 3 reads from Vista 2 and so on)

Comment: for query 1 /Vista 1 is`t it you all repeating the same query any union-ing the same result?
you can insert this result once and use multiple time useing table variable/temp table

Comment: I'm sorry, what is a "Vista"?

Comment: for query 2 please post Actual execution plan.

Comment: @Tomalak - Sorry i wanted to write Views :D

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma - The first View retrives data from three databases and merges everything into a single result.

Comment: can you share some more details about table involved indexes rows ets

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma why? I just wanted to know if the same result is achievable in a better way :)

Comment: Use CTE - Common table expression if you need to use sequence of calculation from more than one view.

Comment: Seems like a lot of repeated functionality. Difficult to say how to do it better without knowing the problem area/data - but it seems too much like 'one-size-fits-all' type query. To solve something like this - I'd likely start over myself, and try to keep it simple from the beginning.